# Low Search + SafeCracker Registration: How To Sort By Distance?

Tags: low-search

We are building a membership site that uses SafeCracker Registration so that Member data can leverage Channels. In the Member associated Channel, it has a latitude and longitude field that's always populated with the Member's geocoded location.

In Low Search, is there a way to apply the Haversine formula to compute the distance between the lat/lng of the logged in member (guests will not have lat/lng) and the lat/lng of the other members and sort by that? Perhaps something like passing a callback function to compute distance to the orderby parameter???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be possible using [Low Search's Distance filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#distance).

If you're using a search form, add a hidden input field that contains the lat/long values of the logged in member, eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="distance:from" value="{cf_member_lat}|{cf_member_long}">
```

...making sure the values are replaced with their actual numerical values. Then, set the `distance:to` parameter, targeting the same custom fields, eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="distance:to" value="cf_member_lat|cf_member_long">
```

Notice the absence of the curly brackets, since we're targeting the fields themselves.

Submitting the form should now give you entries ordered by distance, which you can output using the `{low_search_distance}` variable.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot simpler than having to pass a callback function! What formula do you use to compute distance? If it's not Haversine, then I'll probably want to change the forumula we're using to match -- just for consistency.

Comment: Yes, it uses Haversine.

Comment: So, if these hidden fields exist in the form, the results will be sorted by distance? What if I want the user to explicitly select the way to order by (e.g. by age, by distance, by height, by weight, etc.)? I won't know ahead of time whether or not to include these hidden fields as the user still needs to decide if he/she wants to order by distance. Thoughts?

Comment: You could create a drop down for the `orderby` parameter to let the user choose what to order by. Alternatively, the `orderby_sort` param [is also an option](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#other-native).

Comment: Sorry, now I am a bit confused. I already have `orderby`. How would I make this work for distance? How do I let users select "order by distance?"

Comment: If the `distance:to` and `distance:from` are part of the query, it will automatically order by distance, unless you specifically set the `orderby` parameter to something else. If you need help implementing the feature, check out my [Implementation Aid service](http://gotolow.com/contact).